# Construct a non-unital nuclear $C^*$-algebra without tracial states such that its multiplier algebra is also traceless

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space. The set $K(H)$ of all compact operators is a  non-unital nuclear $C^*$-algebra which has no tracial states and the multiplier algebra of $K(H)$ is also traceless.

My question: do there exist other concrete non-unital nuclear $C^*$-algebras without tracial states such that their multiplier algebras are also traceless?

Comment: Try to think about what happens if you take any such example and tensor it with a C*-algebra.

Comment: You can try twisted tensors also like ergodic group actions on measured space for example.

Comment: @Jamie Gabe，you mean $K(H)\otimes A$?

Comment: @InfiniteLooper, would you mind showing me a concrete example?

Comment: I think you should try to work this out on your own. What would happen if $K(H)\otimes A$ or its multiplier algebra had a tracial state? Or if $B$ is such a nuclear $C^\ast$-algebra, what would happen if $A\otimes B$ or its multiplier algebra had a tracial state?

Comment: Hmmm, what seems harder to come by is examples of traceless A where M(A) has tracial states. I can only think of a very convoluted example.

Comment: @Leonel Rober, what about the examples of tracelss A where M(A) has no tracial states